# How can I store the output of print function to a variable in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a function that prints output to the screen in python. I want the print statements as return value when the function is called.

```
    def printer:
        print("Statement 1")
        print("Statement 2")
        ....
```

instead of the above

```
    def printer:
        return  x
    print(printer())
```

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: I have written code in a function using print . Instead of the print statements in example 1 i want to have the output of print statements assigned to a variable which is returned when the function is called... More precisely i want to append x=print("Statement 1"). It works fine for 1 line of print but for multiple lprint statements how do i do it

Answer (score 1):

You would need to print the statements via a variable and store it in a list, a bit like this:

```
def printer():
    printed_lines = []

    line = "Statement 1"
    print(line)
    printed_lines.append(line)

    line = "Statement 2, etc"
    print(line)
    printed_lines.append(line)

    return printed_lines
```

Comment: If the answer is an accepted solution, consider tagging it like that.